# How to redirect an HttpErrorResponse to the success callback using an interceptor?

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have successfully programmed `HttpInterceptor` which has

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
```

And it has proper `catchError` and `throwError`

```
catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
   return throwError(error)
})
```

Everything is working fine

But I want to convert this to a non error `HttpEvent` so that I can receive both success and error inside the same callback of the `HttpClient` response how do I achieve that?

Comment: I think instead of re-throwing the error you can just return an observable of an `HttpRequest`: return of(new HttpResponse({
           body: error,
           status: error.status,
           statusText: error.statusText
         })) as any;
       })

Comment: thanks, but I need to capture HttpErrorResponse which is 500 error and convert it to 200

Comment: You only want to convert the error if its an 500, else you want to re-throw it?

Comment: I want to receive the error as a proper HttpResponse in the HttpClient callback, if I rethrow it goes the error callback of the subscribe function, I don't want that to happen

Comment: perfect if even without changing status to 200 it still works

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like it only works if you indeed change the `status` property  to a `2xx` -number. Because the critical element that determines if a HttpResponse enters the success callback or the error callback is the value of the status property. Please also see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive the error-response in the same callback as the success-response you have to change the value of the `status`-property of the `HttpResponse` to `2xx`. Otherwise it will still enter the error-callback. At the same time you can assign the original error-object to the `body`-property of your response:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) =>
            of(new HttpResponse({
                body: error,
                status: 200, // if the status is not 2xx, it will enter the error-callback
                statusText: 'OK'
            }))
        )
    );
}
```

**Note of caution**: Modifying the status code of an http-response is usually not considered good practice, yet sometimes it can be a workaround.